# JDBC returns RuntimeError: Java gateway process exited before sending its port number when creating connection with postgres in Pyspark

Tags: postgresql, apache-spark, pyspark, jdbc

creating standard postgres connection with postgres jdbc driver but creating connection itself returns Runtime error.

Code:

```
import findspark
findspark.init()
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
```

```
spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .appName("PostgreSQL Connection with PySpark") \
    .config("spark.jars", "C:/Users/nishi/Downloads/postgresql-42.6.0.jar") \
    .getOrCreate()
```

More info:

working with java version:

```
java version "1.8.0_371"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_371-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.371-b11, mixed mode)
```

& spark version 3.4.0

all environment variables are set, moreover creating spark variable locally i.e. w/o any connection is working fine.

Comment: Can you please add details - when and how are you getting this exception?